Given the sequences $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n$ and $b_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n b_n + b_n$ and $(a_0,b_0)=(\frac{1}{N},0)$ for an integer $N$, show that $b_N=1$.
I am trying to show that given the sequences $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n$ and $b_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n b_n + b_n$ with the initial condition $(a_0,b_0)=(\frac{1}{N},0)$ for an integer $N$, $b_N$ is equal to $1$. I derived the sequence myself, so I am not sure if this is already a well known sequence. I can verify this property using software but I am not sure how to approach this sequence mathematically. I tried writing $b_{n+2},b_{n+3},...$ explicitly but could not find a pattern. I figured that
$$a_{N-1}+b_{N-1}=1,$$ and observed through simulation that
$$a_{\frac{N}{2}} \approx \frac{2}{N},\quad b_{\frac{N}{2}} \approx \frac{1.4}{N}.$$
I welcome any direction on how to approach problems like this. Thank you in advance.

First, let's express $b_n$ in terms of $a_0, \cdots, a_{n - 1}$. We can rewrite the recursion for $b_n$ as
$$b_{n + 1} = (a_n + 1)b_n + a_n^2.$$
This first order recursion can be solved explicitly. Indeed, if we write
$$S_0 = 1, S_n = (a_0 + 1) \cdots (a_{n - 1} + 1)$$
and
$$c_n = \frac{b_n}{S_n}$$
then we have
$$c_{n + 1} = c_n + \frac{a_n^2}{S_n}.$$
Telescoping, we conclude that
$$c_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{a_k^2}{S_k}.$$
So we have
$$b_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} a_k^2 (a_{k + 1} + 1) \cdots (a_{n - 1} + 1).$$
The long product might seem annoying, but the recursion of $a_n$ shows that
$$a_{k} + 1 = \frac{a_{k + 1}}{a_k}.$$
So the product telescopes, and we have
$$b_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} a_k^2 \frac{a_n}{a_{k + 1}} = a_n \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{a_k^2}{a_{k + 1}}.$$
To proceed further, we want to telescope the sum as well. A bit of guessing leads us to, as $a_{k + 1} = a_k^2 + a_k$
$$\frac{a_k^2}{a_{k + 1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{a_k} + \frac{1}{a_{k + 1}}.$$
So the sum also telescopes, leading us to a formula for general $n$.
$$b_n  = a_n \left(n - \frac{1}{a_0} + \frac{1}{a_n}\right).$$
In particular, when $n = N$, we have some cancellation going on
$$b_N = a_N \left(N - \frac{1}{a_0} + \frac{1}{a_N}\right) = a_N \left(N - N + \frac{1}{a_N}\right) = 1$$
as desired.
